# Melt pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe with the following format

| timestamp | ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | UsefulCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2021 | 1 | 0.2 |  | 0.1 |  | Col3 |
| 17/11/2021 | 1 | 0.3 |  | 0.8 |  | Col3 |
| 17/11/2021 | 2 |  | 10 |  |  | Col2 |
| 17/11/2021 | 3 |  |  | 0.1 | 2 | Col4 |

And I want to "melt" it into this format:

| timestamp | ID | Col | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2021 | 1 | Col3 | 0.1 |
| 17/11/2021 | 1 | Col3 | 0.8 |
| 17/11/2021 | 2 | Col2 | 10 |
| 17/11/2021 | 3 | Col4 | 2 |

How would I go about this?

Input as dataframe:

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['16/11/2021', '17/11/2021', '17/11/2021', '17/11/2021'],
                   'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Col1': [0.2, 0.3, nan, nan],
                   'Col2': [nan, nan, 10.0, nan],
                   'Col3': [0.1, 0.8, nan, 0.1],
                   'Col4': [nan, nan, nan, 2.0],
                   'UsefulCol': ['Col3', 'Col3', 'Col2', 'Col4']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a column with the useful values first:

`df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.UsefulCol], axis=1)`

```
timestamp   ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    UsefulCol    Value
16/11/2021  1     0.2             0.1             Col3         0.1
17/11/2021  1     0.3             0.8             Col3         0.8
17/11/2021  2              10                     Col2         10
17/11/2021  3                     0.1     2       Col4         2
```

Then, you can drop the columns you wanted to melt:

`df.drop(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4], axis=1, inplace=True)`

```
timestamp   ID    UsefulCol    Value
16/11/2021  1     Col3         0.1
17/11/2021  1     Col3         0.8
17/11/2021  2     Col2         10
17/11/2021  3     Col4         2
```

Rename your columns if you need:

`df.rename({'UsefulCol':'Col'}, axis=1, inplace=True)`

or

`df.columns = [timestamp', 'ID', 'Col', 'Value]`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a vectorial solution using a bit of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# select columns to pseudo-melt (this could be a manual list cols=['A', 'B', 'C'])
cols = df.filter(regex='^Col').columns

# slice the needed values (they will be on the diagonal) and keep only diagonal
df['Value'] = np.diag(df.filter(regex='^Col').loc[:, df['UsefulCol']].values)

# drop old columns
new_df = df.drop(columns=cols)
```

output:

```
    timestamp  ID UsefulCol     Value
0  16/11/2021   1      Col3    0.1000
1  17/11/2021   1      Col3    0.8000
2  17/11/2021   2      Col2   10.0000
3  17/11/2021   3      Col4    2.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the idea but unfortunately it doesn't work in my situation. I get the error:
"Unable to allocate 125. GiB for an array with shape (129710, 129710) and data type float64". Creating a massive square matrix to take the diagonal is ineffective in my situation. Thanks again

Comment: @MLlearner yes this is not applicable to very large datasets (not sure if this is the reason for the downvote)